# batch file for .png and Julian Dates

Tags: batch-file

quick question. I have a .png format file in Julian dates as the name with sample included in the name . so something like 2006090sample.png. Right now I have a batch file that generates a name.txt file to show the name of the .png as a list
For example:
name.txt
2006090sample.png
2006091sample.png
2006093sample.png

wanted to know if it was possible to write a batch file with the png name and the julian dates next to it and have a  "" in it.
Like this.

2006090sample.png      "Wed, 21 May 780 12:00:00 GMT"

2006091sample.png      "Thu, 22 May 780 12:00:00 GMT"

2006092sample.png    "Fri, 23 May 780 12:00:00 GMT"

Or would I need to create a batch file to rewrite the name everytime a .png is drop  to only have the julian date.

Right now I only have
 dir /B *.png > name.txt

which shows in my name.txt

2006090sample.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
del /q /f name.txt
for %%i in (*.png) do echo %%i "%%~ti" >> name.txt
```